# How to solve Null pointer exception while running a Spring Cloud Function based AWS Lambda

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-lambda, spring-cloud-function

I am trying to upload a simple spring boot application into AWS lambda, but every time i am getting Null pointer exception while calling it from Lambda,Below i am posting the code

DemoApplication

```
package com.example.demo;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
  }
 }
```

SpringBootLambdaHandler

```
 package com.example.demo;
 import org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.aws.SpringBootRequestHandler;

 public class SpringBootLambdaHandler extends 
 SpringBootRequestHandler<String,String>{

 }
```

UpperCaseStringHandler

```
package com.example.demo;
import java.util.function.Function;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class UpperCaseStringHandler implements Function<String,String> 
   {

   @Override
    public String apply(String input) {
    return input.toUpperCase();
    }
  }
```

application.properties

```
 spring.cloud.function.scan.packages=com.example.demo
 cloud.aws.region.auto=false
 cloud.aws.region.static=us-east-1
 cloud.aws.stack.auto = false
 MAIN_CLASS = com.example.demo.DemoApplication
 function.name=upperCaseStringHandler
```

pom.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-function-adapter-aws</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot.experimental</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-thin-layout</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.7</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

Getting the below exception

```
  {
  "errorMessage": "java.lang.NullPointerException",
  "errorType": "java.lang.NullPointerException",
  "stackTrace": [
"org.springframework.cloud.function.context.FunctionalSpringApplication.postProcessApplicationContext(FunctionalSpringApplication.java:102)",
"org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:372)",
"org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)",
"org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.aws.SpringFunctionInitializer.initialize(SpringFunctionInitializer.java:86)",
"org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.aws.SpringBootRequestHandler.handleRequest(SpringBootRequestHandler.java:46)"
 ]
}
```

log output

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.FunctionalSpringApplication.postProcessApplicationContext(FunctionalSpringApplication.java:102) ~[task/:na]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:372) ~[task/:na]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) ~[task/:na]
at org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.aws.SpringFunctionInitializer.initialize(SpringFunctionInitializer.java:86) [task/:na]
at org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.aws.SpringBootRequestHandler.handleRequest(SpringBootRequestHandler.java:46) [task/:na]
at lambdainternal.EventHandlerLoader$PojoHandlerAsStreamHandler.handleRequest(EventHandlerLoader.java:178) [LambdaSandboxJava-1.0.jar:na]
at lambdainternal.EventHandlerLoader$2.call(EventHandlerLoader.java:888) [LambdaSandboxJava-1.0.jar:na]
at lambdainternal.AWSLambda.startRuntime(AWSLambda.java:293) [LambdaSandboxJava-1.0.jar:na]
at lambdainternal.AWSLambda.<clinit>(AWSLambda.java:64) [LambdaSandboxJava-1.0.jar:na]
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [na:1.8.0_201]
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) [na:1.8.0_201]
at lambdainternal.LambdaRTEntry.main(LambdaRTEntry.java:114) [LambdaJavaRTEntry-1.0.jar:na]

java.lang.NullPointerException: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
at  org.springframework.cloud.function.context.FunctionalSpringApplication.postProcessApplicationContext(FunctionalSpringApplication.java:102)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:372)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
at org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.aws.SpringFunctionInitializer.initialize(SpringFunctionInitializer.java:86)
at org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.aws.SpringBootRequestHandler.handleRequest(SpringBootRequestHandler.java:46)

END RequestId: cf38ac86-b6b6-4248-bb85-84326ae7ad76
REPORT RequestId: cf38ac86-b6b6-4248-bb85-84326ae7ad76  Duration: 
3757.95 ms  Billed Duration: 3800 ms    Memory Size: 512 MB Max Memory 
Used: 106 MB
```

Got reference from the below example

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-function

Comment: Are there any package statements in your Java source files?

Comment: @WillisBlackburn yes there are

Comment: please someone help me

Comment: Try to deploy the [original example code](https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-functions) to lambda, then checking the difference if it works.

Comment: @Kane if i upload the code to git will that be helpful to understand the problem?

Comment: If the source is available, I will have a try.

Comment: @Kane https://github.com/iamMandrek/aws/tree/master/demo i have uploaded.

Comment: @Kane can you  please give a try now ?

Answer (score 2):

The NPE can be resolved by adding below env for your lambda,

```
MAIN_CLASS = com.example.demo.DemoApplication
```

See [this issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function/issues/350) for more detail

ps:

I did deploy your code via [serverless framework](https://serverless.com/), below is the configuration example of serverless for your reference,

```
service:
  name: spring-cloud-function-npe

frameworkVersion: ">=1.0.0 <2.0.0"

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: java8
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'} # Set the default stage used. Default is dev
  region: ${opt:region, 'ap-east-1'} # Overwrite the default region used. Default is ap-southeast-1
  stackName: spring-cloud-function-npe-${self:provider.stage} # Use a custom name for the CloudFormation stack
  apiName: spring-cloud-function-npe-${self:provider.stage} # Use a custom name for the API Gateway API
  profile: ${opt:profile, 'default'} # The default profile to use with this service
  memorySize: 1024 # Overwrite the default memory size. Default is 1024
  timeout: 6 # The default is 6 seconds. Note: API Gateway current maximum is 30 seconds
  logRetentionInDays: 14 # Set the default RetentionInDays for a CloudWatch LogGroup
  deploymentPrefix: serverless # The S3 prefix under which deployed artifacts should be stored. Default is serverless
  versionFunctions: true # Optional function versioning
  endpointType: regional # Optional endpoint configuration for API Gateway REST API. Default is Edge.
  logs:
    restApi: true

package:
  individually: true

functions:
  springCloudFunctionDemo:
    handler: com.example.demo.SpringBootLambdaHandler::handleRequest # required, handler set in AWS Lambda
    name: ${self:provider.stage}-spring-cloud-function-npe # optional, Deployed Lambda name
    description: spring-cloud-function-npe # optional, Description to publish to AWS
    memorySize: 384 # optional, in MB, default is 1024
    timeout: 100 # optional, in seconds, default is 6
    reservedConcurrency: 5 # optional, reserved concurrency limit for this function. By default, AWS uses account concurrency limit
    tracing: PassThrough # optional, overwrite, can be 'Active' or 'PassThrough'
    environment: # Function level environment variables
      FUNCTION_NAME: UpperCaseStringHandler
      MAIN_CLASS: com.example.demo.DemoApplication
    package:
      artifact: target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Then deploy and invoke the lambda,

```
sls deploy
sls invoke -f springCloudFunctionDemo --data "hello world"
```

Comment: No function defined: java.lang.IllegalStateException
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No function defined
 at org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.aws.SpringFunctionInitializer.apply(SpringFunctionInitializer.java:134)
 at org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.aws.SpringBootRequestHandler.handleRequest(SpringBootRequestHandler.java:48)